# Get PHP Eclipse to run error checking on different file-types

Tags: php, eclipse, validation, file-type, syntax-checking

In my project I have a series of `*.tpl` files that I would like `Eclipse` to interpret as PHP code.  I have managed to get syntax highlighting to work properly for these files by adding a `*.tpl` entry in `Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Content Types`.  However this does not seem to also enable syntax error checking / validation.

So to be clear, I would like `Eclipse` to show me per-line errors in the editor and also indicate any errors/warnings on the files in the PHP Explorer - for files with a `.tpl` extension.  Currently neither is happening.

I have tried also adding `*.tpl` to `Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations`.  I have tried pressing `F5` in various relevant places, and have tried restarting `Eclipse`.  The folder with the `*.tpl` files is a subdirectory of a source folder.  Other subdirectories of this source folder are working correctly (although they have `.php` files).  I don't know what else to do.  Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for trying out everything I could think of off the top of my head. Cheers mate!

Comment: I think this should be in [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/eclipse)

Comment: I did consider that Mihai, but I thought this is closer to programming than simply general computing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's bizarre.  I just tried to test Ashutosh's example and it worked.  After creating a new file test.tpl, all of a sudden all other .tpl files in the project started being parsed/validated properly and all the warning/error icons suddenly appeared.

So this seems like a bug in this version of Eclipse (http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt/downloads).  Hopefully this is a repeatable workaround for anyone else who experiences the problem though!

Thanks very much guys.

Comment: I suggest [posting a detailed bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) of this while the incident is still fresh. I had a similar problem in the past, but I neglected to report it. (IIRC, it fixed itself when I closed all the open editors of the files that weren't being treated as PHP and then re-opened the workspace.) ([Eclipse bug-reporting FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_report_a_bug_in_Eclipse%3F))

Comment: I have just tried to repeat this from scratch so as to produce such a report, but I'm incredibly frustrated to find it will not work a second time around.  I am back to square one! :/

Comment: No worries, same thing happened to me. =P It's not a huge problem, and if anyone else encounters it, they should be able to solve it with the help of this page.

Comment: Yeah agreed. I hope it's not too long till I re-stumble across whatever combination of prods gets it to work! :p

Comment: I have gone from scratch 3 times and have carefully tried to identify what combination of events gets the validation process to start for the .tpl files.  Unfortunately the best I can say is that it seems to need a certain amount of time until it "just works".  In my case, about 15 minutes.  During that time I added *.tpl to the Content Types page and then did various things such as creating .tpl files and/or using Project > Clean... a number of times.  I'll update this if I can clarify any of this further.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I tried creating a custom `*.guvava` and was able to do so by adding `*.guvava` to `Content Types` and `File Associations`. When I opened up a new guvava file after that, I had everything I would have in a java file.

[image]

[image]

[image]